# How to make a "Reached Destination" notification on Android?

Tags: android, gps, location, broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an app that simply asks the user to enter an address and close the app then using a broadcast receiver, when the person reaches the location, a notification is displayed.
I've been trying different ways for days... would truly appreciate good help with code!

Comment: I really don't appreciate your tone Sapid, I have tried codes but they are useless

Comment: Post the code you have tried! You should appreciate any helpful feedback which puts the topic forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gps service or network servicet find the location of your current position. then by refreshing every 10 or 30 second  you can check whether your position is equal or near the the position you entered.If yes then you can use broadcast receiver to generate anotification.

I think it will give you a idea how to do this

Comment: Wouldnt that drain the battery ?

Comment: Maybe you can refactor the approach to take into acount the distance from your destination for the first interval. Lets say your riding on a bus and you're 2 hours away. Only start notificatiobs after 1:30